# Alert deprecated: Stdlib.String.set

Tags: ocaml

The following code returns an error and says that the syntax is deprecated. What is the correct way to change a character in a string?

```ml
let hello = "Hello!" ;;
hello.[1] <- 'a' ;;
```

```
Alert deprecated: Stdlib.String.set
Use Bytes.set instead.
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         bytes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable (or at least soon they will be), so you can't change their contents. You can, of course, create a copy of a string with the one character different, e.g.,

```
let with_nth_char m c = 
  String.mapi (fun i b -> if i = m then c else b)
```

and

```
# with_nth_char 1 'E' "hello";;
- : string = "hEllo"
```

But if you need to change characters in an array then you shouldn't use the `string` data type but instead rely on `bytes` which is a type for mutable strings.  You can use `Bytes.of_strings` and `Bytes.to_string` to translate strings to bytes and vice verse.